# Find the merge point of two LinkedLists : Run time error

Tags: java, linked-list, runtime-error

I have wrote the code which finds the merge point of two linkedLists, But in most test cases hackerrank  throws run time error, I just wanted to know what causes it. Here is my code below:

```
static int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode head1, SinglyLinkedListNode head2) {
  SinglyLinkedListNode node1 =  head1;
  SinglyLinkedListNode node2 = head2;
  if(node1.next == node2){
    return node1.data;
    
  }
  else if(node2.next==node1){
    return node2.data;
    
  }
  if(node1 ==node2){
    return 0;
    
  }
  if(node1 ==null || node2==null){
    return 0;
    
  }
  while(node1 !=null && node2 !=null){
    node1=node1.next;
     node2=node2.next;  
     if(node1==node2){
         break;
       }
     }
     return node1.data;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It does not show the error.

Comment: Maybe you should run some test cases yourself and see if you can find it? Otherwise we can only guess without knowing the error or the line it occurs on.

Comment: I'm guessing one of their tests has either `head1` or `head2` as null, making your first `if/else` a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

```
if(node1.next == node2){
  return node1.data;
}
```

If indeed the above condition is true, then the merge point is not `node1`, but `node2`, so the wrong data is returned here. The same mistake is made in the similar `if` block that follows.

```
if(node1 ==node2){
  return 0;
}
```

The above `if` clearly identifies a merge point, but it is wrong to return 0. It should return `node1.data`.

```
if(node1 ==null || node2==null){
  return 0;
}
```

The above code would mean there was no merge point. Given that the challenge promises that there is a merge point, this case will never happen.

```
while(node1 !=null && node2 !=null){
  node1=node1.next;
  node2=node2.next;  
  if(node1==node2){
    break;
  }
}
```

The above `while` loop assumes that the distance to the merge point is the same in both lists, but you cannot assume this. It might be that the first list has the merge point at its 6<sup>th</sup> node, while that node is only the 3<sup>rd</sup> in the second list. So the `while` loop will pass over the merge point without noticing it.

Then after the loop you have:

```
return node1.data;
```

But there is like 50% probability that the `while` loop ended because `node1` became `null`. And if that happens the expression `node1.data` will trigger an exception, which is what you saw happening.

As a conclusion we can say that your algorithm is not good enough for this task.

#### A solution

There are several ways to approach this, but one way is to first *count* the number of nodes in the first list and in the second list. If one is longer than the other, then you can already dismiss the first few nodes from the longest list so that you are left with two lists that are just as long. At *that* moment your `while` loop would do the job, as then you can be sure the distance to the merge point is the same in both lists.

Here is the suggested code for that:

```
// Helper function to count the number of nodes in a given list:
static int size(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
    int size = 0;
    while (head != null) {
        head = head.next;
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}

static int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode head1, SinglyLinkedListNode head2) {
    // Get the difference in list's sizes
    int sizeDiff = size(head1) - size(head2);
    // Dismiss the first node(s) from the longest list until they have an equal size:
    while (sizeDiff < 0) {
        head2 = head2.next;
        sizeDiff++;
    }
    while (sizeDiff > 0) {
        head1 = head1.next;
        sizeDiff--;
    }
    // compare the remaining nodes in tandem.
    while (head1 != head2) {
        head1 = head1.next;
        head2 = head2.next;
    }
    return head1.data;
}
```